# In PostgreSQL how do you insert into a table with only one identity column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, identity

For instance:

```
{create table Participant ( id serial, primary key(id) );}
```

How do you insert into table in this case?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you create the table like above,

You can use `default` in following way to insert:

```
INSERT INTO Participant values(default);
```

Check out **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/6d38a/2)**.

Another way to insert is:

```
INSERT INTO Participant values(NEXTVAL('Participant_id_seq'));
```

`CREATE TABLE` will create implicit sequence `"Participant_id_seq"` for serial column "`Participant.id"`.

You can get the sequence for the table using `pg_get_serial_sequence` function in following way:

```
pg_get_serial_sequence('Participant', 'id')
```

It will take new value from sequence using `NEXTVAL()`.

Check out **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/83374/4)**

Comment: The simplest, most portable and cleanest way is to use `DEFAULT` as you've shown above; IMO that should be shown before the `nextval` approach and preferred to it.

Comment: Also don't forget you can use returning as in: insert into pariticipant values (DEFAULT) returning id;

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into Participant values (default);
```